# How to find grid last row value of any specific column using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have grid like following

My grid id is `Grid`

```
Home   Reading Value
abc    9        a1
bnc    0        a2
```

Now I want to check for column `Reading` who's last value is `0` make that a `NA`

I tried like following

```
function Changes() {
            var column;
            $("#Grid thead tr th").each(function () {

                var txt = 'Reading';
                 column = $('#Grid thead tr th').filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text() === txt;
                }).index();                 

            });
            $("#Grid tbody tr td:eq(" + column + ")").each(function () {
                debugger;
                if ($(this).text() == "0") {
                    $(this).text("NA");
                }
            });
        }
```

For Html
[image]
But it is not working I missed something ?

Comment: can you share the html for the table

Comment: no html dynamically created Grid

Comment: instead of the image, share the html from the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure about the position of the Reading(the last cell) then you can try

```
function Changes() {
    var index = $("#Grid thead tr > *").filter(function () {
        return 'Reading' == $.trim($(this).text())
    }).index();
    $('#Grid tbody tr td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').text(function (i, text) {
        return $.trim(text) == '0' ? 'NA' : text;
    });
}
Changes();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m8Hu3/)

The problem with your selector `$("#Grid tbody tr td:eq(" + column + ")")` is, it selects the cell at the given index across all rows because `#Grid tbody tr td` returns all the tds and it takes the one at the given index `column` instead of finding the given index in each row

Comment: @ashuthinks since you said it is the last column that parts are not required

Comment: but we need to find the `column header` right ? which will return `2` which is nothing `Reading`

Comment: But What If `Reading` column is not at last ? it is inbetween thats why i was lookuing for cilumn header index and depending upon that making chnages PLEASE HELP

Comment: thanks working fine... please let me know about `(index + 1)` and `thead tr > *")`

Comment: `(index + 1)` - .index() returns 0 based index where as nth-child uses 1 based index so we increment the index by 1

Comment: `thead tr > *` instead of that you can easily use `thead tr th`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the last value is 0? like the last row that have a 0?

You could try

```
var column = $("#Grid thead tr th").index(":contains(Reading)");

$("#Grid tbody tr td:eq(" + column + "):contains(0):last").text('NA');
```

Here you can check what it does http://jsfiddle.net/4YmzW/

Comment: but i'm getting column value as '-1' not 'Reading'

Comment: var column will have the index .. -1 means it did not found it ... it could be something wrong with the selector? or the spelling of Reading?

Comment: i guess something could be wrong with selector :/ i tried with all column names too same -1

Comment: well it works on the fiddle so if you fix the selector it could work .. $("#Grid thead tr th") have to select all the header ... so .index(":contains(Reading)") will return the index of the header that match the selector .. in this case the one that have the text "Reading " inside